# Saving ArrayList values after form submission

Tags: java, forms, jsp, struts2

How to add value from `textfield` to an `ArrayList` of `String`s and after form submission have the possibility to add other values, without losing all previously saved?

The expected result is that after every form submission the `list` has one `String` more.

Adding submitted value to `ArrayList` in `Action` class doesn't work, because after the next form submission, it does **not** contain previously added value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Issue: -** *Adding submitted value to `ArrayList` in Action class doesn't work, because after the next form submission, it does not contain previously added value.*

Ans- **It wont persist  data in your `ArrayList` as instance of your action class gets created for per request**.

So you either have an option to store it in `database` to make the persist.And every time when user request it you `query your database` to retrieve `List` of your `textfield` values.

And if you are talking about single session then you can even `textfield` values into a `session`.

Comment: Regarding to struts 2 framework the submitted values are stored in session. So when I type value into `textfield`, after submission this `texfield` displays last typed value, so it means that property which was connected to this `textfield` was stored in the session. Isn't possible to automatically store `ArrayList` the same like value from `textfield`?

Comment: @KamilChaber Not like that.This is not how `struts` works.Its not the value in `session` you are seeing.You are seeing `cached value`.The only way you can do it is storing `request parameter` value in **`persistent storage` if you want it across the users** o/w **if you want them per session you can store them `per session`** as well.You can populate your `ArrayList` in action class with `textfield` values but it will be available to that request only.Make sure about how do you want to store it whether `per session/per request/for every request`

Comment: @KamilChaber Make a use of `SessionAware interface` to get `session` variable.Thanks for voting up.

Answer (score 2):

store it in the session and retrieve it. or use a database to save the string and retrieve it

EDIT:

```
session.setAttribute("listName",list);
```

will store your list in the session that will be available for that particular user